# Accessing inputs from ng-model with variable names

Tags: javascript, angularjs

instead of uploading a bunch of code, I drew a little schema for you guys. This picture shows of pretty good my current situation (abstract). The second picture is the current situation in "reality".

If I press on "Send" inside the e.g. `bigBox_1`, I want all the inputs from the `littleBox_1` ... `littleBox_n` inside the `bigBox_1` being transferred to my function.

Which is the best way of doing it?

I tried to name my ng-models (inside `littleBox_1` ... `littleBox_n`) dynamically, but I couldn't figure out a solution how to pass all the parameters.

Some facts:

- I don't know how many big boxes there will be
- I don't know the amount of little boxes inside my big boxes
- The amount of little boxes inside different big boxes are not necessary the same

Reality:
[image]

Abstract:
[image]

The model schema for the boxes:
[image]

Comment: it's probably better if you'd share some code so we can help you fix it.

Comment: it's hard to tell how the data you have is structured from your post but if you have an array of objects you can just make a directive to display them. here's an example plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/T606DGaOMCvsKEAad6Xc?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/bmCom5BLMJ0VdIz6cqih?p=catalogue

Comment: what would be useful is an example of the data you have in the box variable. :)

Comment: box contains a JSON Objekt. this is the mongoose model:
http://i.imgur.com/9KxdAmo.png

Comment: and out of that box what do you want to send back to the server?

Comment: look my plunker; I want to send back what the user entered inside the little Boxes.

Comment: well, the way binding usually works when the user changes something it should be changed back in your box object, so you should be able to send the box back. :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="box in boxes">
            <label ng-bind="box.id"></label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="box.name" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="addInput()">Add input</button>
    <button ng-click="startFunction()">start Send inputs value</button>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module("testApp", [])
        .controller("testCtrl", function ($scope) {

            var i = 0;

            $scope.boxes = []; //is empty

            $scope.addInput = function () {
                $scope.boxes.push({ id: i++ });
            }

            $scope.startFunction = function () {
                console.log($scope.boxes);
            }

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i hope this is what you want ;)